# How to read the statistics for LinkedIn posts?

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to create a simply app to get statistics (read, liked, commented) for my LinkedIn posts. 
LinkedIn sends me a periodic emails with this statistics, but I can't find the correct API for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve number of likes and number of comments via the network updates API once you have obtained the `key` for a specific post (="share"):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://www.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key=UPDATE-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx?format=json" | jq '.numLikes, .updateComments._total'
```

that info is also available in the list of updates as obtained from:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"  https://www.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?format=json
```